# Moving Docker's overlay folder to a network drive

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I run a Docker swarm cluster and I am a bit frustrated that every node keeps all the images on it's local storage.
If I run a Postgres13 on node1, the image is downloaded and stored on it's local hard drive.
Then, if I spawn Postgres13 on the node2, that node again downloads the image and stores it on it's local drive.

I am using the overlay2 storage driver, so it's all in /var/lib/docker/overlay2.

I was wondering if it is possible to have the nodes share the overlay2 folder: my plan was to create a new directory on a network share (gpfs mounted to /dfs) and bind-mount said new directory to /var/lib/docker/overlay2 on each node.

My understanding is, that since this is only about the images, no user data should be written to this folder and only contain the image data beautifully ordered using their hash.
So at best, the nodes would now find images that are already downloaded.

Did anyone ever try this or knows if this would work?

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to think this would cause issues if two docker instances attempted to pull the same image at the same time, as there is nothing synchronizing access to the shared drive.

If you are just looking to speed up image downloads, perhaps look into running your own instance of Docker registry, configured as a pull through cache?